# How can we migrate magento 1 EE to magento 2 CE

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento-1.14, data-migration-tool, magento2.3.0

I have a site in EE and want to migrate to magento CE 2.3.0 from magento 1.14.1.0

Did anyone has already migrated or had some plan how can we migrate it without any issue with current data?

Answer (score 1):

you may follow plan describe below to migrate to Magento CE 2.3.0 from Magento 1.14.1.0

- **Data Migration :**
  You can use Magento [Magento 2 Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html) to migrate Data from Magento 1.X to Magento CE 2.3.0.

First, need to install [Magento 2 Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html) and then you need to set it up by editing configuration xml files in ***vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/***.

For any mismatch tables fileds between Magento 1.X & Magento 2 Database, you have to Igone or map those fields for Magento 1.X to Magento2.X tables. Please check this link for more information  [https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento2-data-migration-tool/][2] .

It may long process (depending on custom tables and Custom Fields on Magento 1 Database) because until you map or Ignore all mismatch field, Data Migration Tool will not complete the migration process.

- **Code Migration**

For code migration, you need to find out / install Magento 2 version of all Magento 1 modules. You can ask the vendor for an updated version on all of Magento 1 Modules.

If any customization has done on templates file (*.phtml) in Magento 1 project, then you need to implement those customizations in Magento 2

- **Test Migration**

It is a better plan to do a Test Migration first. Install a fresh Magento 2, then dump Magento 1 database into your localhost and do the data migration task.

After you successfully migrate Data, then go for Code (Extenstion and Customization) Update.

- **Media Migration**

  For Media files (like Products images, Categories Images, CMS pages Images) migration , you need to Copy & Paste media files from Magento 1 media Directory ( **magento1root/media**) to Magento 2 pub/media directory (**magento2root/pub/media**).

Once you will be done with  Data Migration, Media Migration, and Code Updates, then you can go for data migration from your Live Magento 1 site.

Below are some useful links you can check for Magento 1 to Magento 2 Data migration process.

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

https://www.magespark.com/blog/post/boost-the-performance-of-your-online-ecommerce-store-with-the-best-magento-2-migration-service

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento2-data-migration-tool/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: Solid answer. Magentos free Data Migration tool is sufficient but 3rd party tools can often be easier to use for the less technical

Answer (score 0):

- I would watch this before even considering a migration.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6kpN6Tb6Qc&t=9s
- Still relevant, if you are worried about the release date.